# OnMouseDown fires more than once in Scatterplot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, google-visualization

I'm using React at work and we are using Google Charts to showcase some data. Now showing the data works alright. It's a bunch of data points that can be filtered by checking some checkboxes.

When you click a checkbox, the whole dataset is reevaluated so that the entries that don't match filters gets taken out. Then the filtered data is put in a separate collection, before that filtered dataset is being put back in the Chart object for showing.

Now when no filters are applied and all data is shown, the `onmousedown` event fires completely normal. Just once. However when I apply a filter (or any number of filters really) the `onmousedown` event fires multiple times. Some times the event returns data from points I didn't click. But every time it also returns data that I did click on, just multiple times.

I don't quite understand this behaviour:

```
<Chart
chartType="ScatterChart"
width="100%"
height="480px"
loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
data={filteredData}
options={chartOptions}
rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}
chartEvents={[
  {
    eventName: 'ready',
    callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
      const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
      google.visualization.events.addListener(
        chart,
        'onmousedown',
        e => {
          const { targetID } = e;
          if (targetID.includes('point')) {
            const tableEntry = FlowUtil.getChartEntryOnClick(
              filteredData,
              targetID,
            );
            handleOnMouseClick(tableEntry);
          }
        },
      );
    },
  },
]}
/>
```

Is it because I need to use a different event, or is it because I'm handling the event all wrong? Or is it because I'm changing the data out and caching is the culprit? I'm kind of out of ideas here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the event is fired multiple times,
because it is added multiple times,
every time the chart's `'ready'` event fires.

before adding the listener, remove all previously added listeners,
by using --> `google.visualization.events.removeAllListeners(chart);`

see following snippet...

```
chartEvents={[
  {
    eventName: 'ready',
    callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
      const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();

      google.visualization.events.removeAllListeners(chart);

      google.visualization.events.addListener(
        chart,
        'onmousedown',
        e => {
          const { targetID } = e;
          if (targetID.includes('point')) {
            const tableEntry = FlowUtil.getChartEntryOnClick(
              filteredData,
              targetID,
            );
            handleOnMouseClick(tableEntry);
          }
        },
      );
    },
  },
]}
```

Comment: It looks like my comment disappeared. I just wanted to thank you!